# Cannot submit a form in django template from javascript

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django

I have the following django template. I am submitting the form through javascript, because ultimately I want that the submit button will be hidden, and the form will autosubmit when the input text changes (i want it to autosubmit when a "." is the last character in the text):

```
<form action="/rewrite/" method="post" id="sentence">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <textarea name="inp" id="ans">abc</textarea>
    <input type="button" value="Submit" name="new_stop" onclick="submitForm()" id="but">
</form>

<script>
    function submitForm()
    {
        form.submit();
    }
</script>
```

Upon clicking the button I get a

```
Forbidden (403)

CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.
```

error

Comment: where does the JS variable `form` come from? You might want to try something like `document.getElementById("#sentence").submit();`

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the CSRF Token is not included within your button's scope.

Try this instead:

```
<form onsubmit="myFunction()">
    <input type="button" value="Submit" name="new_stop" id="but">
</form>
```